# Suddenly vite keeps on restarting server

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-typescript

I have following default code in vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

It was working perfectly fine since a month, suddenly it keeps on restarting in loop saying like

```
vite.config.ts changed, restarting server...
6:10:43 PM [vite] .env changed, restarting server...
6:10:43 PM [vite] .env.dev changed, restarting server...
6:10:43 PM [vite] server restarted.
```

Whereas nothing being changed in these files.

I have vite version 4.3.9

Comment: I've had this with vite + vue too. Did you get anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I installed playwright because the fsevents version got deduped to version 2.3.2, which has a bug that causes this. The bug is fixed in `fsevents@2.3.3`

I did this and it seems to work now

`npm i -D fsevents@2.3.3`

And I added this to my package.json

```json
  "overrides": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.3"
  },
```

I found this github issue in chokidar that talked about it. https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/1286